# How to await an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-2017

My case:

```js
let waiting = function () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('awaiting...');
    
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  });
};

let waitingAsync = async function () {
  console.log('start...');

  await waiting();

  console.log('stop...');
};

waitingAsync();
console.log('done...');
```

There are 2 things I don't understand in the code:

The first:

```
await waiting();
```

`waiting` is a synchronous function (because it doesn't have `async` keyword). So, why can I await a synchronous function?

The second:

Why couldn't `done...` message be awaited after completing `waitingAsync` function?

And main question: `waitingAsync` is an asynchronous function, why is `await` keyword not required when calling it? Just `waitingAsync()` instead of `await waitingAsync()`.

If I can await `waitingAsync()`, `done...` message would be printed last.

Comment: `async` does not mean that the return value of a function can be awaited with `await`. A function can be awaited if it returns a `Promise`, which `waiting` does in your example. But `async` is necessary on a function, like on the `waitingAsync` function, to enable the use of `await` within it.

Comment: Additionally, the return value of the `waitingAsync` function is automatically turned into a `Promise`, since it can no longer give a synchronous result. So it can now be awaited. But it's not the only way for a function to be able to be awaited, since if it was, you wouldn't be able to write the first such function to begin with.

Comment: _`async` does not mean that the return value of a function can be awaited with
`await`_. ~ * ~ ***False!*** -
[__Every `async` function returns a `Promise` object__](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43422983).
The only caveat in this case is that the Promise returned by the function `waiting` evaluates
to no value (void), by the line `resolve();`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a function but a value that it returns which is awaited with `await` statement.

`async` and normal functions aren't different to the caller. `async` just returns a promise without returning it explicitly when being called. The result of `waitingAsync()` call is a promise. The result of `waiting()` call is a promise, too, so it isn't 'synchronous'.

According to [the spec](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait), both promises and non-promises can be `await`ed. Non-promises are converted to promises with `Promise.resolve()`.

`console.log('done...')` can't be awaited because it isn't called inside `async` function. And it doesn't have to be `await`ed because it doesn't return a promise but `undefined`. `await`ing it would be possible within `async` function. These `await` usages are equal and equally useless, all they do is 1 tick delay:

```
async function ... {
  ...
  await console.log('done...');
}

async function ... {
  ...
  console.log('done...');
  await undefined;
}

async function ... {
  ...
  await Promise.resolve(console.log('done...'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `async` function does return a promise or, when it uses the `await` keyword, it must wait for a asynchronous function, being a Promise or another `async` function. In your code, `waiting()` is a function that returns a Promise. Then, `await waiting()` is correct (since it is waiting for a asynchronous function).

An `async` function is called as another basic functions is called. You may mark a function as async when you desire operate it as an asynchronous function and using the 'await' keyword. The 'done...' is printed because when you call `asyncFunction()`, it must `await` until `waiting promise` is finished. But the program is not stopped and go on showing `done...`. If you want to wait for it, maybe you can use `asyncFunction().then( () => console.log('done...') )`

Comment: _"A async function must return a promise"_  It **does** return a promise.

Answer (score 2):

`Async` keyword used to specify that function will be an instance of `AsyncFunction` so it will return `Promise`.

`Await` is used to wait for a promise resolving inside of async function.

---

[According to a mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) - async function can contain an `await` expression, that pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value.

Answer (score 2):

When you `await` a function, if that function returns a promise, its return value will be treated as the promise `then` value. If the promise will reject, it will be cast to an Error. If the function call returns something ohter than a thenable, well, `await` then just doesn't nothing.

In the other hand, when you declare an `async` function, its return value will be returned as a Promise, and any Error thrown from it will be casted to a rejected Promise.

You can use `await` only within an `async` declared function.

that's just about `async` and `await`are, just automatic casting to promises. You don't actually need code using await and async to be really asynchronous (while, well, it's not really useful).

A quick demonstration:

```
//Will return the string 'Promise' if called through `await`
function getPromise(){
    return Promise.resolve('Promise');
}

//Casted to Promise.reject thrught await 
function throwError(){
    return Promise.reject('error'); 
}

function get(){
    return 'something simple'; 
}

async function getAsync() {
    var response = await getPromise();
    return response;
}
//await will cast the rejected Promise to an error
async function getErrorAsync() {
    var response = await throwError();
    return response;
}

async function simpleGet(){
    return get();
}

async function redundantGet(){
    return await get();
}

    async function catchTheError(){
      try{
          await throwError();
      }       
      catch(e){
         console.log('an error: ' + e );
      }
       return 'whatever';
 }

getAsync().then( console.log ); //Promise
getErrorAsync().catch( console.log ); //error
simpleGet().then( console.log ); //something simple
redundantGet().then( console.log ); //something simple
catchTheError(); //will log 'an error: error'.
```

So:

> waiting is a synchronous function (because it doesn't have async keyword). So, why can I await a synchronous function?

Because you can. The only thing `await` does is to resolve promise to real values and errors. You don't actually need the function to return a promise.

> Why couldn't done... message be awaited after completing waitingAsync function?

`async` and `await` only makes your code to behave as it would be synchronous iside `async`declared functions. Your last `console.log('done')` is outside any `async` function, so it will be just logged before that function ends, since it is asynchronous.

> And main question: waitingAsync is an asynchronous function, why is await keyword not required when calling it? Just waitingAsync() instead of await waitingAsync().

Because `async` keyword casts values to promises -and allows to use `await`- and nothing more. In fact, since you can only use `await` inside `async` functions... you can't expect `async` functions to be called through `await`, you would need infinite `async`functions :-D.

Answer (score 1):

Before diving in, it's good to notice a few things.
Any reader of the code snippet

```js
let waiting = function () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('awaiting...');
    setTimeout(function () { resolve(); }, 1000);
  });
};

let waitingAsync = async function () {
  console.log('start...');
  await waiting();
  console.log('stop...');
};

waitingAsync();
console.log('done...');
```

may be mislead to believe that the output will be

```
start...
awaiting...
stop...
done...
```

while – as you have already noted – `done...` gets printed *before*
`stop...`.

The reason is that `waitingAsync();` is a call to an *asynchronous* function,
while `console.log('done...');` is just a normal sequential/synchronous
statement that gets carried out right away.

---

*Question 1*:

> `waiting` is a *synchronous* function (because it doesn't have `async`
> keyword) [?]

*Answer*:
***False.*** The function `waiting` *is **a**synchronous* – *it returns
a Promise*.

---

*Question 2*:

> Why couldn't `done...` message be awaited after completing `waitingAsync`
> function?

*Answer*:
Because `console.log('done...')` is ***not*** asynchronous.
(It does *not* return a Promise.)

---

*Question 3*:

> And main question: `waitingAsync` is an asynchronous function, why is
> `await` keyword not required when calling it?

*Answer*:
Well, in your example `waitingAsync` does not return any value. -
If it *would* return a value that you care about, then you would need to await
it to get it.
(`Hello world!` in my Stack Snippet below.)

---

*Question 4*:

> If I can await `waitingAsync()`, [the] `done...` message would be printed
> last [?]

*Answer*:
That depends on what exactly you mean. – See my Stack Snippet below!
As long as the `Done!` message is printed within the same callback as the call
`await waitingAsync()`, the answer is *Yes!*
But if you put `console.log('done...?')` *after* the call to the asynchronous
function that encloses `await waitingAsync()` then the answer is *No!*

---

When running the snippet below, pay attention to the *order* of the output!
Also notice how it takes 1400 *ms* for `Promise resolved!` to show up.

```js
function waiting () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log('awaiting...');
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve('Hello world!');
      console.log('Promise resolved!');
    }, 1400);
  });
}

async function waitingAsync () {
  console.log('start...');
  const toBeReturned = await waiting();
  console.log('stop...');
  return toBeReturned;
}

(async () => {
  console.log('Heads up! The next line makes an asynchronous call.');
  console.log('Result: ' + await waitingAsync());  // 'Hello world!'
  console.log('Done! This will be printed LAST! - Agreed?');
})();

console.log('done...?? This is LAST in the CODE. - I awaited \
"waitingAsync()" above. - So will this be printed at the very end??');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The last asynchronous function is anonymous – without name – and gets
called immediately.
In fact, this is the only function that gets called *directly* in the snippet.
The function `waitingAsync` is only called ***in**directly* (by the anonymous
function), and the function `waiting` is also called *indirectly*
(by `waitingAsync`).

#### A take away lesson

*Don't ever put sequential/synchronous code **after and outside** a call to
an asynchronous function!*

You will just confuse yourself if you do. – And even if *you* don't get
confused, *other readers* of your code almost certainly will be.